# Google Cloud Storage (Nearline) - Incremental/differential backup tool

Tags: backup, cloud-storage

Looking for a backup tool that can do incremental/differential backups to Google Cloud Storage (nearline).

Currently I'm using a command line tool (Gsutil) provided by Google. However, I find it's not verbose enough. I would like to see more details like how long it will take (estimated time), current speed / second, etc.

Besides, it doesn't do incremental / differential backups.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using CloudBerry Backup.
It supports Google nearline and allows you to perform incremental and differential backups.

More information here:
http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-s3-cloud-desktop-backup.aspx

Regards,
Vlad,
CloudBerry Lab

Comment: Is there some more information about how it does incremental/differential backups? Didnt see anything related. Thanks

Comment: Sorry,

I should have provided more details.
The following articles describe in more details:
http://www.cloudberrylab.com/incremental-backup-vs-differential-backup.aspx
http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/block-level-backup-and-full-backup-explained/

Comment: Thanks, one question I still have is: For incremental backups, suppose I do the first backup (the full one) then I remove 1000 files from my folder and then I run a second backup (the first incremental) so what does happen to the files I deleted ? Appear as removed in the 2nd, incremental backup? Or only files modified? If so, what happens when I restore the backup? Will I get the 1000 removed files back? even when I removed them because I don't need them anymore?  I'm confused as to how incremental backups work in regards of deleted files. Thanks

Comment: You can customize the way how CloudBerry handles such cases per your requirements. More information here:
http://www.cloudberrylab.com/help/backup/backupwizard_automatedeletionoflocallydeletedfiles.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Arq (Arqbackup)](https://www.arqbackup.com) is another backup solution that can do incremental backups to various local and cloud storages including Nearline.